# Can't hide cart in local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart, local.xml

I've tried hiding the cart button in the top header area with multiple xml commands in the local.xml file, but non work.  I've tried `<remove name="checkout_cart_link" />` nested under a `<default>` tag, as well as `<reference name="top.links"> <remove name="checkout_cart_link" /> </reference>`based off of [THESE](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remove-the-%E2%80%9CMy-Cart%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9CCheckout%E2%80%9D-menu-links-in-Magento) instructions.

I'd prefer to keep the edits in local.xml if possible.  Also, we have a quote add-on installed (cart2quote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just the incorrect reference and name.  Correct ones are `<reference name="header">` and `<remove name="minicart_head">`.

If anyone knows how to look up the reference names and block names, please share!